# React Hooks - Infinite loops when setting a state within a map

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, infinite-loop

For reference: I am working on a sliding puzzle game.

So I have a const Board function and I have defined 2 states named:

- puzzlePieces
- hiddenIndexNumber

The point of 'hiddenIndexNumber' is to keep track of the hidden block index within the game. So before the game starts, I loop through a new array that I create for puzzlePieces and use map to return HTML elements. When looping, I want to make sure that I get the hidden block index for my hiddenIndexNumber to keep track of the hidden block.

This is how my code (partially) looks:

```
const Board = () => {

    const totalPieces = 9
    const hiddenNumber = totalPieces
    const[hiddenIndexNumber, setHiddenIndex] = useState(-1)
    
    // here I create an array of 9 elements and shuffle them with underline
    const [puzzlePieces, changePuzzlePieceContent] = useState( 
        _.shuffle( [ ...Array( totalPieces ).keys() ].map( num => num + 1 ) ) 
    )

    let puzzleElements = [ ...Array( totalPieces ).keys() ].map( index => {
        // the problem here is that setHiddenIndex makes the framework rerender
        // the DOM after setting the index number and I don't know how to solve the issue here
        if( puzzlePieces[index] === hiddenNumber ) {
            setHiddenIndex(index)
        }

        return <Puzzle 
            key         = { index }
            index       = { index }
            number      = { puzzlePieces[index] }
            hidden      = { puzzlePieces[index] === hiddenNumber && true }
            onChange    = { handleChange }
        />
    } )
}
```

The problem is with this code:

```
if( puzzlePieces[index] === hiddenNumber ) {
    setHiddenIndex(index)
}
```

How do I make sure that I set hiddenIndexNumber without requesting for rerendering the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look into `shouldComponentUpdate()` and `useEffect()` Hooks.
It's well described here: [shouldComponentUpdate()?](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-prevent-rerender-component) with an example.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look on it soon.